# OData.Feed error when querying Azure DevOps Analytics $batch endpoint

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I've written a Power Query like the following:

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$top=1"
        , null, [Implementation="2.0", OmitValues=ODataOmitValues.Nulls, ODataVersion=4, MaxUriLength=1, EnableBatch=true])
in
    Source
```

But I'm getting back an unexpected error:

```
Stack Trace:
Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SerializedException
Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: The method or operation is not implemented. ---> Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: The method or operation is not implemented. ---> Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: The method or operation is not implemented. ---> Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: The method or operation is not implemented. ---> Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: The method or operation is not implemented. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.HttpRequestBuilder.CreateSingleBatchedODataQuery(MashupHttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, Uri uri, Value innerRequestHeaders, String contentType, ODataServerVersion version)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.HttpRequestBuilder.BuildWebRequest(HttpResource resource, Uri serviceUri, Uri uri, Value headers, ResourceCredentialCollection credentials, ODataSettingsBase settings, String contentType, IEngineHost host, ODataUserSettings userSettings, ODataServerVersion serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataRequest.BuildWebRequest(IResource origin, Uri uri, IResource& resource)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Web.Request.ManualRedirect(IEngineHost host, String resourceKind, Uri uri, CreateWebRequestDelegate createRequest, Func`2 createResponse, WebRequest& webRequest, Int32[] nonErrors)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataRequest.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<GetResponseStream>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Common.RetryPolicy.Execute[TResult](IEngineHost host, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataRequest.GetResponseStream(IHostTrace trace, String key, Boolean tokenRefreshed)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataRequest.GetResponseStream()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataModule.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<TryDetectODataV4Feed>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataFallbackVersionHandler.HandleVersionFallback[T](Func`1 function, Boolean throwOnBadRequest)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataModule.TryDetectODataV4Feed(HttpResource resource, Value headers, IEngineHost host, ResourceCredentialCollection credentials, ODataUserSettings userSettings, StandaloneODataFallbackVersionHandler fallbackHandler, Uri serviceUri, Uri uri, ODataSettingsBase settings, HttpResponseData& responseData)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataModule.GetFeed(HttpResource resource, TextValue serviceUriValue, TextValue uriValue, Value headers, IEngineHost host, ResourceCredentialCollection credentials, ODataSettingsBase settings, ODataUserSettings userSettings, Boolean useCachedCredentials)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataModule.FeedFunctionValue.TypedInvoke(TextValue serviceUri, Value headers, Value options)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.NativeFunctionValue3`4.Invoke(Value arg0, Value arg1, Value arg2)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.DebugInstruction.Execute(MembersFrame1& frame)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.FunctionInvocationInstruction2.Execute(MembersFrame1& frame)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.DebugInstruction.Execute(MembersFrame1& frame)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.InstructionInvocationInstruction2.Execute(MembersFrame1& frame)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.DebugInstruction.Execute(MembersFrame1& frame)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.MembersFunctionValue1.Invoke(Value arg0)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordInstruction.RuntimeRecordValue.Force(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordInstruction.RuntimeRecordValue.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.MembersFunctionValue1.Invoke(Value arg0)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordInstruction.RuntimeRecordValue.Force(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordInstruction.RuntimeRecordValue.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.Library.Linker.BindFunctionValue.TypedInvoke(RecordValue environment, Value section, TextValue name)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.NativeFunctionValue3`4.Invoke(Value arg0, Value arg1, Value arg2)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.MembersFunctionValue0.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.ListInstruction.RuntimeListValue.Force(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.ListInstruction.RuntimeListValue.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.MembersFunctionValue1.Invoke(Value arg0)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordInstruction.RuntimeRecordValue.Force(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordInstruction.RuntimeRecordValue.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.FunctionInvocationInstruction2.Execute(MembersFrame1& frame)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.Instruction.ExecuteCondition(MembersFrame1& frame)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.DebugInstruction.ExecuteCondition(MembersFrame1& frame)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.IfInstruction.Execute(MembersFrame1& frame)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.DebugInstruction.Execute(MembersFrame1& frame)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.MembersFunctionValue1.Invoke(Value arg0)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordInstruction.RuntimeRecordValue.Force(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordInstruction.RuntimeRecordValue.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.MembersFunctionValue0.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SimpleDocumentEvaluator.BeginGetResult(DocumentEvaluationParameters parameters, Action`1 callback)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SimpleDocumentEvaluator.BeginGetResult(DocumentEvaluationParameters parameters, Action`1 callback)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SimpleDocumentEvaluator.BeginGetResult(DocumentEvaluationParameters parameters, Action`1 callback)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.IDocumentEvaluatorExtensions.GetResult[T](IDocumentEvaluator`1 evaluator, DocumentEvaluationParameters parameters)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.OnBeginGetResult[T](IMessageChannel channel, BeginGetResultMessage message, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.OnBeginGetPreviewValueSource(IMessageChannel channel, BeginGetPreviewValueSourceMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.OnMessageWithUnknownChannel(IMessageChannel baseChannel, MessageWithUnknownChannel messageWithUnknownChannel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.Run()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.Run(Object args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SafeThread2.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreateAction>b__0(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.SafeRun(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.Main(String[] args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SimpleDocumentEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<BeginGetResult>b__0(EvaluationResult2`1 result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SimpleDocumentEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<BeginGetResult>b__0(EvaluationResult2`1 result)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SimpleDocumentEvaluator.BeginGetResult(DocumentEvaluationParameters parameters, Action`1 callback)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SimpleDocumentEvaluator.BeginGetResult(DocumentEvaluationParameters parameters, Action`1 callback)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.IDocumentEvaluatorExtensions.GetResult[T](IDocumentEvaluator`1 evaluator, DocumentEvaluationParameters parameters)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.OnBeginGetResult[T](IMessageChannel channel, BeginGetResultMessage message, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.OnBeginGetPreviewValueSource(IMessageChannel channel, BeginGetPreviewValueSourceMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.OnMessageWithUnknownChannel(IMessageChannel baseChannel, MessageWithUnknownChannel messageWithUnknownChannel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.Run()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.Run(Object args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SafeThread2.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreateAction>b__0(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.SafeRun(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.Main(String[] args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<OnBeginGetPreviewValueSource>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<RunStub>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.ReportExceptions(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Action action)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<TryReportException>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Common.SafeExceptions.IgnoreSafeExceptions(IEngineHost host, IHostTrace trace, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.TryReportException(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.ReportExceptions(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.RunStub(IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Func`1 getPreviewValueSource)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.<OnBeginGetResult>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.ReportExceptions(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.OnBeginGetResult[T](IMessageChannel channel, BeginGetResultMessage message, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.OnBeginGetPreviewValueSource(IMessageChannel channel, BeginGetPreviewValueSourceMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.OnMessageWithUnknownChannel(IMessageChannel baseChannel, MessageWithUnknownChannel messageWithUnknownChannel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.Run()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.Run(Object args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SafeThread2.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreateAction>b__0(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.SafeRun(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.Main(String[] args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.OnException(IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, ExceptionMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.IMessageChannelExtensions.WaitFor[T](IMessageChannel channel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.PreviewValueSource.WaitFor(Func`1 condition, Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.PreviewValueSource.get_TableSource()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.TracingPreviewValueSource.get_TableSource()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Analysis.PackageDocumentAnalysisInfo.PackagePartitionAnalysisInfo.SetPreviewValue(EvaluationResult2`1 result, Func`1 getStaleSince, Func`1 getSampled)
```

I've set `MaxUriLength=1` in order to force it to use the $batch endpoint, but the same issue occurs when I don't set it and my query is much longer. Additionally, if I don't set `MaxUriLength=1` and I use a shorter query, I don't get any errors and the query works fine. According to the [Azure DevOps docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/odata-batch?view=azure-devops#the-analytics-batch-endpoint):

> The $batch endpoint is not available with a project scope, but the queries within a batch can contain project scoping.

I'm not sure how to express that in Power Query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We restrict use of the batch endpoint from handling a batch of multiple requests. A single request can still have only one query.

Comment: @Jeff Gotcha, thanks; am I unknowingly sending multiple queries in one request? Cheers.